# Autofilling of utterances in alexa skills generated by utterance generator tool(ex. utternance expander)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

Is there any API or way to integrate the utterance generator to alexa skill developer console.

Means I want the generated utterances by generator tool to be autofilled in the alexa skills intents in develope console.

Does developer console provide any means of calling the utterance generator API and to get it included into respective intents in alexa developer console.

Answer (score 1):

The developer console right now does not support any means of calling external API to autofill utterances.

However, One solution would be to write a simple program in one of your preferred languages to create a JSON file according to [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-schema.html) format.

You can generate all the utterances into this file and copy and paste the file in the interaction model JSON editior in amazon skill developer console and it would automatically create intents and utterances according to the Interaction model Json you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

A solution very useful, with nested parentheses and JSON format you'll find in [this site](http://www.makermusings.com/amazon-echo-utterance-expander/).

This tool will help you enumerate the sample utterances that your Amazon Echo app will recognize for your intents